# Make PHP variable evaluate as 'plain' text

Tags: php

I have two PHP variables that seem to have the same value, $dynamic which is produced from a function and $test which is just text in single quotes.

When I print their values they're the same, but the $dynamic fails in regex functions.

Is there any way to make a PHP string 'not dynamic' and just plain old text

```
$test = 'username'; //Evaluates OK
die($test.' '.$dynamic); //Produces: username username
```

Below is the function, $pattern is the issue. This is actually from an earlier question, but I've since narrowed the issue to the evaluation of $pattern. This also seems to be an issue with other functions besides preg_replace_callback.

```
public function output() {
if (!file_exists($this->file)) {
    return "Error loading template file ($this->file).<br />";
}
$output = file_get_contents($this->file);

foreach ($this->values as $key => $value) {
    $tagToReplace = "[@$key]";
    $output = str_replace($tagToReplace, $value, $output);


    $dynamic = preg_quote($key);
    $test = 'username';

    $pattern = '%\[if @'.$test.'\](.*?)\[/if\]%'; // produces: %\[if @username\](.*?)\[/if\]%

    $output = preg_replace_callback($pattern, array($this, 'if_replace'), $output);
}

return $output;
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "$dynamic fails in regex functions"?  Please add an example to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Can we see the function?

Comment: Can you show the code where you're assigning to `$test`, as well as the function?

Comment: @MikeB: Sorry, didn't mean to ask you.

Comment: Sorry I should have posted the function to start. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible `$dynamic` may contain invisible characters. Loop over the string and print the character code of each character (use `ord`) - and compare that with the result for `"username"`.

`var_dump` might also give hints as it will show the length of the string as well.

Comment: Thanks. Good suggestion, var_dump for $dynamic had 8 characters and looks like ASCII codes are the same.